# existence of antiderivative without Cauchy-Goursat's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I wonder if anybody has tried the following kind of direct proof for the existence of an antiderivative of an analytic function on a star-shaped domain.

Theorem: Let $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on a star-shaped domain $D$. Then $f$ has an antiderivative $F$ on $D$.

"proof": For simplicity, assume that every point in $D$ is connected to $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ by a line segment. Define
\begin{equation}
F(z) = \int_0^1 zf(zt)dt.
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{ F(z+h)-F(z)  }{h} \right) = \lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{(z+h)f(zt+ht)-zf(t)}{h} \right) dt.
\end{equation}
 It can be checked that as $h \to 0$, the integrand converges to 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} tf(zt).
\end{equation}

Therefore, $F'(z) = f(z)$, provided that the limit and integral are interchangeable. qed.

Of course, a limit and integral cannot always be interchanged. But I wonder  if anybody seriously considered the above line of proof.

Thanks. As far as I can search from several textbooks in complex variables, the above theorem is proved by using Cauchy-Goursat's theorem. More concretely, they use the equality
\begin{equation}
\int_{z_0}^{z+h} f(z)dz \ - \ \int_{z_0}^z f(z)dz \ = \ \int_z^{z+h} f(z)dz,  
\end{equation} 
which can be justified by Cauchy-Goursat's theorem. The point of my question is:
Is it possible to directly invoke to the computation as above, without using Cauchy-Goursat's theorem? If this is possible, we get another proof of Cauchy-Goursat's theorem, at least for star-convex domains.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you please clarify what exactly is being asked here? There doesn't appear to be a precise question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand *exactly* what you want to ask, but perhaps this is helpful:

> A continuous function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ has an anti-derivative on $\Omega$ if and only if 
>   $$ \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0 $$
>   for every simple closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$.

In other words, it seems difficult to completely circumvent some variant of Cauchy-Goursat.